# Apache Ignite as unified facade for several DB or another persistence

Tags: java, architecture, dao, ignite

I need to use several DB in my project. And also I have to use distributed cache - for this I chose Apache Ignite. As Ignite is more than just a cache I think about idea to use it as facade to relation DB and nosql DB. But after reading a lot of documentation I can't understand how to do this.

Is there way to make Ignite only point for saving or getting data and hide all needed DB's behind it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to implement your own `CacheStore` and properly configure a cache.
The comprehensive description is available at [Apache ignite. 3rd Party Persistence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store)

`CacheStore` examples can be found here: [JDBC-based cache store implementation](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/jdbc)

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But in this way I need to know about every DB in my project. My idea is to create some proxy classes that should be integrated in Ignite on its server side and my project should think that it works with the only DB when operating data with Ignite.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Could you elaborate on your question in more detail? Some pseudo code snippet would be nice as well.

Comment: The idea is that I don't want to know about any real DB in my project. Application should know only about separate Apache Ignite server. All communications with real DBs should do Ignite server.

Comment: I think you would need to create multiple caches and configure different CacheStore implementations for each cache to go to a specific database. This way your application will need to know about Ignite caches only, without knowing about the underlying database.